# problem to search a word in pdf file with "Document Viewer"?

Tags: pdf

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.

I downloaded a PDF file for my academic requirements. When I open this PDF with Document Viewer, it displays the contents of the file. However, when I start searching (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) for a word in the file, it gives me "no word is found" for every attempt even though it is present the file?

How can I search for the word in the PDF?

Comment: Maybe the pdf is just an image, with no OCR behind?

Comment: More reading: [Is that PDF Searchable?](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2007/02/is_that_pdf_sea/) and [How to know if a PDF contains only images or has been OCR scanned for searching?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1489733/1771119)

Comment: are you able to select text in the document? If not the text is probably only pictures. and as far as I know there is not a lot you can do.

Comment: Another possible explanation: the PDF library evince is based on, poppler, [isn't capable of searching across newlines](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11381). If your term extends across two lines sadly you won't be able to find it with *any* PDF viewer that is based on poppler (e.g. evince, okular, qpdfview...).